# Display contracts array with web3

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have the following array in my smart contract:

```
string[] public saved_texts;

function getSavedTextsCount() public constant returns(uint) {
    return saved_texts.length;
}
```

I created `getSavedTextsCount` to basically get the length of my array.

My `web3` function looks like the following:

```
  basicInfoUpdate: function () {
    TextContract.deployed().then(function (instance) {
      let element = ''
      for (let index = 0; index < instance.getSavedTextsCount; index++) {
        element += instance.saved_texts.call(index)
        element += '</br>'
      }

      document.getElementById('transactions').innerHTML = element
    })
  },
```

However, I  do not get any result back. Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `instance.getSavedTextsCount` call in the wrong way

`instance.getSavedTextsCount` is an asynchronous method so you need to wait until it responds with a value.

the correct way to implement your idea will be :

```
var text_count;
instance.getSavedTextsCount.call().then(
   data => {
    text_count = data[0].c;
    var element ;
    for (let index = 0; index < text_count; index++) {
         instance.saved_texts.call(index).then(
            elemdata => {
              element += elemdata[0]
              element += '</br>'
            }
         )
        document.getElementById('transactions').innerHTML = element
      }


})
```

**NOTE  :** please verify that `data[0].c` is existing, because usually  that is what you get hen you call return uint from solidity using web3 call.

**NOTE :** is is better to use `instance.getSavedTextsCount.call()` than `instance.getSavedTextsCount()` when you are not adding data to storage, it uses less or no gas than the direct call, which should be reserved to methods that change storage.